# Monotonicity test for multivariable regression

Tags: r, regression, linearity

I have dataframe as follow:

```
y <- c(35.3, 37.2, 33.1, 35.7, 35.7)
x1 <- c(141.0, 142.5, 139.5, 141.7, 138.4)
x2 <- c(61.2, 55.8, 66.4, 58.7, 70.1)
x3 <- c(67.1, 69.7, 64.5, 65.6, 72.5)
x4 <- c(14.5, 15.1, 13.9, 14.2, 15.7)

df <- cbind(y, x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

In here, 'y' calculated by x1 ~ x4, but the model is black-box.
--> y ~ f(x1) + f(x2) + f(x3) + f(x4)
I only show 5 data in each variable, in reality there are at least 50 data per variable.

In this case, I want to measure the linearity and monotonicity of this model.
I wonder if there is best way.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you mean that $y$ is created by $x_1\sim x_4?$

Comment: Hello Dave, y = f(x1) + f(x2) + f(x3) + f(x4). In here, each function is black-box. So I don't know exact equation. That's why I want to test linearity and monotonicity.

Comment: Is this all the data you have or is it just a sample for illustration?

Comment: Hello Dipetkov, It is just a sample. I have 50 samples each variable at least.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "monotonicity" in this context?  Is $f$ specified or somehow fit to the data? If the former, then what is it; and if the latter, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chunk test for linearity is straightforward. It's sufficient to compare two models: a model that's linear in all predictors and a model that allows the additive effect of each predictor, *f(x<sub>i</sub>)*, to be nonlinear (and smooth). I use the `mgcv` package to specify a GAM model with thin plate splines.

Testing for monotonicity is a bit trickier but still possible within a spline framework, given the right choice of splines. I use the `scam` package to specify a constrained additive model (SCAM) with monotonic splines.

To illustrate, I simulate three datasets: *y = x1 + x2 + x3 + f(x4) + noise* with a linear, monotonic and quadratic form for the function *f(x4)*. And I fit three models to each dataset: M1 is a linear regression, M2 is a GAM with (constrained) monotonic splines and M3 a GAM with (unconstrained) splines. I use ANOVA to compare the three models.

*Linear relationship*

[image: linear]

```r
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#>   Res.Df     RSS        Df  Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
#> 1 95.000 0.88808                                      
#> 2 94.888 0.88588  0.112000  0.0022007 2.1047 0.09206 .
#> 3 94.961 0.88735 -0.073442 -0.0014647 2.1362 0.07362 .
```

*Monotonic relationship*

[image: monotonic]

```r
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#>   Res.Df    RSS     Df Sum of Sq        F    Pr(>F)    
#> 1 95.000 756.66                                        
#> 2 93.634  11.15 1.3664    745.51 36157.55 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> 3 91.374   1.38 2.2594      9.77   286.52 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

*Quadratic relationship*

```r
#> Analysis of Variance Table
#> 1 95.000 2486.4                                       
#> 2 94.581 1282.4 0.41854      1204 186542 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> 3 90.620    1.4 3.96152      1281  20969 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

[image: quadratic]

---

R code to reproduce the simulation and analysis:

```r
library("mgcv") # thin plate splines
library("scam") # monotonic splines
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

n <- 100

data <-
  tibble(
    x1 = runif(n, -4, 4),
    x2 = runif(n, -4, 4),
    x3 = runif(n, -4, 4),
    x4 = runif(n, -4, 4)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    noise = rnorm(n, sd = 0.1),
    y_linear = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x4 + noise,
    y_monotonic = x1 + x2 + x3 + (x4 > 0) * x4**2 + noise,
    y_quadratic = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4**2 + noise,
  )

fit_models <- function(data, k = 5) {
  m0 <- lm(
    y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
    data = data
  )
  m1 <- scam(
    y ~
      s(x1, k = k, bs = "mpi") + s(x2, k = k, bs = "mpi")
      + s(x3, k = k, bs = "mpi") + s(x4, k = k, bs = "mpi"),
    data = data
  )
  m2 <- gam(
    y ~
      s(x1, k = k, bs = "tp") + s(x2, k = k, bs = "tp")
      + s(x3, k = k, bs = "tp") + s(x4, k = k, bs = "tp"),
    data = data
  )
  list(m0, m1, m2)
}

models <- fit_models(data %>% rename(y = y_linear))
anova(models[[1]], models[[2]], models[[3]])

models <- fit_models(data %>% rename(y = y_monotonic))
anova(models[[1]], models[[2]], models[[3]])

models <- fit_models(data %>% rename(y = y_quadratic))
anova(models[[1]], models[[2]], models[[3]])
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your great answer! But, I has one more question about your answer. In the second model (y_monotonic), it seems to be more good fitting when apply the GAM( ). How can I determine it is monotonic or not?

Comment: Good point. Notice however that the monotonic spline doesn't quite fit the monotonic $y$. Try increasing the number of knots. For example I tried `models <- fit_models(data %>% rename(y = y_monotonic), k = 11)` to use 11 knots. Then check the ANOVA output.